# which is the best performance way to achieve XML column info to set object's field

Tags: c#, xml, reflection

I have field object array (field containing fieldname/fieldvalue fields) which I need to set into `Info` class for related columns match to fieldname (as defined below XML).

```
public class Info
{
  public string col1 {get; set;}
  public string col2 {get; set;}
  public datetime col3 {get; set;}
  public datetime col4 {get; set;}
  public datetime col5 {get; set;}

}
```

XML is as follow:

```
 <columninfo>
    <column name="col1,col2" fieldname="c1" type="string" />
    <column name="col3" fieldname="c3" type="date" format="ddMMMyyy"/>
    <column name="col4,col5" fieldname="c4" type="string" format="ddMMMyyy"/>
 </columninfo>
```

Example:
   fieldname="c1" then, need to set two columns -col1,col2 of info class., if fieldname="c3" then, need to set "col3" of info class with particular dateformat as defined `format` attribute.

How to achieve this where it can be fastest way by performance.
two things - one is to read XML to some object or directly parse XML to find matching for fieldname's related column. second thing, to set column of `Info` class based on fieldname/value.

---

one of the sol: to read the XML and create `dictionary<fieldname,fieldobject>`
and then, string=fieldname => dictionary[fieldname].name to read the columns and set for value. But not sure, how to set value with particular format.
also, I have name as property and dont' want to do switch case.

Thanks

Comment: Can you change the xml structure?

Comment: yes, it can be change if needed but, there are so many XML for each entry. so, if needed then it can be done.

Comment: So why not use [XML Serialization](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part)?

Comment: dont' have value in xml and also, fieldname receive as single in each iteration.

Comment: Where do you get the values from?

Comment: I get from third party API, it come as collection and I need to iterate to retrieve value. so, each time, I get single value and that needs to find into XML to fetch related columns and those need to set into `info` class.

Comment: Can you give a larger example of the "field object array"?

Comment: it 10-14 around fields of collection and each object containing- name property and value property). You can consider, each time I have single field that needs to process to find in XML and set in `info` class for related matching property.

Comment: You may pre-process the xml by xslt and after that use the XML serialization

Comment: there are single single property so, XSLT transform to muitiple class and set each time property value (also, not have value). I have updated question with some answer, that I think to apply.